# Order of files in org-agenda-files

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to use all the files contained in a directory, say `OrgAgendaDir`, as my `org-agenda-files`.
Moreover, among the files contains in `OrgAgendaDir`, I would like to put specific files, say `file1.org` and `file2.org`, first in the list, so that these files are the first ones visited by `org-cycle-agenda-files`.
So I tried to set the variable like so:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("/fullpath/OrgAgendaDir/file1.org" "/fullpath/OrgAgendaDir/file2.org" "/fullpath/OrgAgendaDir"))
```

But it doesn't work: `org-cycle-agenda-files` now only cycles between `file1.org` and `file2.org`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this helps `C-c [ (org-agenda-file-to-front)` https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Files.html. Furthermore have a look at the emacs option named `Org Agenda File Regexp`

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce it. To help us debug, evaluate the expression `(org-agenda-files)` and edit your question to add the result. Assuming that it is correct (i.e. it includes the files you are interested in, in the order you want), it should work.